Flickering Login Screen on Windows 10 After Cloning HDD
Yesterday I decided to clone my old, dying 1TB HDD (it had bad sectors showing up) to a new 2TB drive. Both are MBR, and I'm on BIOS. I used OpenSuperClone via OSC-Live for the process (cuz of the bad sectors) and it took around 2 hours (ended directly after Phase 1, so I assume it went normal). Once the clone was complete, I physically removed the old drive before booting into Windows from the new one.
At first, it seemed like everything was fine: I saw the Windows loading screen as usual, but as soon as it got to the login screen, the screen started flickering like crazy link. [FLICKER WARNING!]
Also, weirdly, the clock on the login screen was wrong for some reason. (It was fixed later.)
I’ve tried searching online for solutions, but nothing has really worked so far:
So, I booted into Windows repair mode and opened up CMD. I used diskpart to list volumes and noticed that the drive letters were incorrect and system partition had a letter assigned to it (not sure if that’s normal or if CMD in Windows Repair messes with drive letters.) Anyway, I tried changing it back how they were before using assign letter=<letter> and attempted to boot into Safe Mode using bcdedit /set {Default} safeboot minimal (since F8 didn’t seem to work for some reason).
Once I booted into Safe Mode, everything worked fine. I was able to log in, and everything—files, desktop, apps—was intact. I checked diskpart and disk management, and everything seemed normal—no missing partitions, no obvious errors. The drive letters were back to normal. So, I disabled Safe Mode using bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot and clicked on restart to boot into normal Windows.
To my surprise, it worked! Windows booted normally, and I could use the PC like nothing was wrong. Desktop loaded, files were accessible, everything seemed fine. I figured the issue was solved. But then, when I shut the PC down and tried booting it up the next day, the flickering login screen issue came right back :(
So, I’m back to square one. But, for some reason, restarting from Safe Mode from before fixes the issue temporarily, but doing a cold boot from shutdown brings the flicker back every time.
One thing I noticed is that cold booting leads the login screen quickly (compared to restarting from Safe Mode, which takes longer to reach the login screen). I have never used fast boot and I'm pretty sure it was turned off. Although I did use S3 Hybrid Sleep. So, I disabled hibernation (thinking maybe hibernate.sys was causing problems) using powercfg /hibernate off, but the issue still persists.
I also tried plugging the old HDD back in to test if it was a drive-specific issue. The old HDD boots into Windows perfectly fine without any flickering issues, so this seems to be related to the clone or the new drive itself.
Since the flickering issue goes away when in Safe Mode, I feel like it’s gotta be something with third-party services or drivers—but what’s confusing is that they do load just fine after restarting from Safe Mode, so why does cold booting trigger the flicker?
Does restarting from Safe Mode prevent anything from loading?
Does anyone have an idea of what’s going on here? How can I diagnose this further? I'm really stumped here... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

That behavior isn’t from the system being cloned only the GPU would cause that behavior and because it works in safe mode which doesn’t end up using certain portions of the gpu I suspect you have a gpu that’s failing. In my experience your issue is caused by the hardware not the drivers themselves

@Ramhound How come it works after restarting from safemode? I've got an Nvidia GPU and I'm on the PC right now using that weird method to boot in.
And like I said, it works totally fine without the messy workaround when on the old drive.

Windows 11 keeps flickering (turn fully black) after upgrading it from windows 10 is another report of a flickering screen. It was reported that disabling Windows fast start initially stopped the flickering, but the flickering returned after a hibernation. Not sure if check if fast start is disabled on the your new HDD would help.

@ChesterGillon Okay, I just checked again to make sure, and sure enough, HiberbootEnabled is 0 in the registry

@N00B_141 - If it’s a clone of the drive, the flickering can’t possibly be caused by a driver, since presumably it’s the same driver
